# как объединить два numpy массива разных форм?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Пример кода:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([0,1,2,3])
array2 = np.array([0])
```

Что должно получиться на выходе:

```
[[0,1,2,3],[0]]
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, зачем вам тогда вообще numpy? делайте обычней списки с подсписками любой размерности. numpy тоже позволяет так делать _но только для типа данных object_, и при этом весь смысл использования numpy теряется.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не так?

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
array2 = np.array([0])

new_array = [array1, array2]
print(new_array)
```

Вывод:

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0])]
```

---

Если на выходе надо получить именно списки, то так:

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
array2 = np.array([0])

new_array = [list(array1), list(array2)]
print(new_array)
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0]]
```